# In-place C++ set intersection

Tags: c++, stl, set

The standard way of intersecting two sets in C++ is to do the following:

```
std::set<int> set_1;  // With some elements
std::set<int> set_2;  // With some other elements
std::set<int> the_intersection;  // Destination of intersect
std::set_intersection(set_1.begin(), set_1.end(), set_2.begin(), set_2.end(), std::inserter(the_intersection, the_intersection.end()));
```

How would I go about doing an in-place set intersection?  That is, I want set_1 to have the results of the call to set_intersection.  Obviously, I can just do a `set_1.swap(the_intersection)`, but this is a lot less efficient than intersecting in-place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
std::set<int>::iterator it1 = set_1.begin();
std::set<int>::iterator it2 = set_2.begin();
while ( (it1 != set_1.end()) && (it2 != set_2.end()) ) {
    if (*it1 < *it2) {
        set_1.erase(it1++);
    } else if (*it2 < *it1) {
        ++it2;
    } else { // *it1 == *it2
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
    }
}
// Anything left in set_1 from here on did not appear in set_2,
// so we remove it.
set_1.erase(it1, set_1.end());
```

Anyone see any problems?  Seems to be O(n) on the size of the two sets.  According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/), std::set erase(position) is amortized constant while erase(first,last) is O(log n).

Comment: The continues are redundant, and I'd rearrange to be `if(*it1<*it2) else if(*it2<*it1) else ...` so that the only comparison operator you're using is less than - that's how `set` works.

Comment: Right!  Because it's if-else if, etc.  I was thinking the following conditionals would be checked.  Thanks, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: `set_1.erase(it1++)` is incorrect for some containers (such as vector), even if it is valid in your case. You should use `it1 = set_1.erase(it1)` that is valid with all containers.

Comment: Would it1 be incremented properly in that case?  That is, does set_1.erase(it1) increment the iterator?

Comment: `set::erase` doesn't increment the iterator, but many implementations give you the incremented iterator as a return value. I don't think it was part of the original C++ spec though, see for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily go through `set_1`, check each element to see if it exists in `set_2`, and erase it if it doesn't. Since sets are sorted, you can compare them in linear time, and erasing an element using an iterator is [amortized constant time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase).  I wouldn't count on it being more efficient than what you started with though, benchmarking would be wise if it matters to you.

Comment: True enough on all points.  It seems to me intuitively that it should be possible to iterate through both sets at once and do the intersection in place.  I just don't immediately see how.

Comment: The erase operation on a single element of a balanced binary tree runs in `O(log N)`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod no, it's amortized constant. I didn't know that when I wrote the answer, but I know it now, and I've updated to reflect that.

Comment: Interesting that the standard is _requiring_ that sparse tree balancing. I would have thought that would be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

It's not directly answers the question, but maybe someone find this helpful.

In case of `std::vector` it is **not** safe to use standard algorithm with `set_1.begin()` as output iterator (see below), while [clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/algorithm#L5398-L5419)/[gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bd82a079cee55e2bbf02c794bbd1ce7903154497/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L5390-L5412)/[microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/f4f3acde831e3262a5d3889454c27ca09a07f44a/stl/inc/algorithm#L4009-L4033) implementations **would work**. Note, `set_2` *could be anything*, not just a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> set_1;  // With some elements
std::vector<int> set_2;  // With some other elements
auto end = std::set_intersection(
                     set_1.begin(), set_1.end(), 
                     set_2.begin(), set_2.end(), 
                     set_1.begin() // intersection is written in set_1
                    );
set_1.erase(end, set_1.end()); // erase redundant elements
```

**Update**:

Thanks to @Keith who found that C++ Standard (25.4.5.3) requires next:

> The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges

So what I initially proposed was **wrong**, but working solution in major STL implementations. If you want to be on safe side and don't want extra allocations then copy implementation of your choice to you code base and use it instead of `std::set_intersection`. I don't really understand reasons for such restriction, please comment if you know the answer.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this being safe? I want to do this, but the only sources I've found (all of which are non-authoritative) say [e.g.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) "The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges."

Comment: Good catch! Strictly speaking you are right, the cppreference page explicitly prohibits it. I have no idea what is the origin of this restriction.  

I derived "safety" from the *possible implementation* and next two facts. Size of set intersection does not exceed size of `set_1` and no iterators are invalidated during the procedure. As far as I can see the only side effect of violating the rule is self assignments of elements of `set_1` during procedure.

Comment: cppreference cites paragraph from standard exactly (25.4.5.3), so one cannot rely on in unfortunately. A workaround would be to copy a standard implementation to your code base which will guarantee it.